# Should I keep a similar tests for Unit Testing and DBUnit testing in a Data Mapper?

Tags: php, unit-testing, dbunit

I've been practicing and reading about test driven development.
I've been doing well so far since much of it is straightforward but I have questions as to what to test
about certain classes such as the one below.

```
    public function testPersonEnrollmentDateIsSet()
    {
        //For the sake of simplicity I've abstracted the PDO/Connection mocking
        $PDO = $this->getPDOMock();
        $PDOStatement = $this->getPDOStatementMock();

        $PDO->method('prepare')->willReturn($PDOStatement);
        $PDOStatement->method('fetch')->willReturn('2000-01-01');
    
        $AccountMapper = $this->MapperFactory->build(
            'AccountMapper',
            array($PDO)
        );

        $Person = $this->EntityFactory->build('Person');
        $Account = $this->EntityFactory->build('Account');
        $Person->setAccount($Account);
        $AccountMapper->getAccountEnrollmentDate($Person);

        $this->assertEquals(
            '2001-01-01',
            $Person->getAccountEnrollmentDate()
        );
    }
```

I'm a little unsure if I should even be testing this at all for two reasons.

#### Unit Testing Logic

In the example above I'm testing if the value is mapped correctly. Just the logic alone, mocking the connection so no database. This is awesome because I can run a test of exclusively business logic without any other developers having to install or configure a database dependency.

#### DBUnit Testing Result

However, a separate configuration can be run on demand to test the SQL queries themselves which is another type of test altogether. While also consolidating SQL tests to run separately from unit tests.

The test would be exactly the same as above except the `PDO` connection would not be mocked out and be a real database connection.

#### Cause For Concern

I'm torn because although it is testing for different things, it's essentially duplicate code.

If I get rid of the unit test, I introduce a required database dependency at all times. As the codebase grows, the tests will become more slow over time, no out-of-box testing; extra effort from other developers to set up a configuration.

If I get rid of the database test I can't assure the SQL will return the expected information.

My questions are:

**Is this a legitimate reason to keep both tests?**

**Is it worth it or is it possible this may become a maintenance nightmare?**

Comment: Just write a mock for PDO. I notice in your code you have no error checking

Comment: @EdHeal I have mocked PDO, but did you read that I don't know how much or what I should be testing?

Comment: There is very little you can unit test. You do not take into account any return values.

Comment: @EdHeal That's a fairly vague comment. I don't follow.

Comment: Unit testing - Follow all the code paths - You have one. So only one possible test

Comment: Which is? Actually, could you post it as an answer with more detail if you think you know the answer?

Comment: You have no loops/if statements in `getAccountExpirationDate` One entry and one exit. The mock can just check for that PDO is being fed the right stuff

Comment: @EdHeal PDO is being fed a few parameters which would be one test per assertion. I'm confused since you said "one" possible test.

Comment: You are not testing PDO. There is only one route through that method

Comment: That wasn't what I meant. I was wondering if you meant that the test you're talking about is for the `PDO` mock to expect `execute`, `prepare` being called, etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, it seems like you want to test what PDO is doing. (Are `prepare`, `execute` etc ... being called properly  and doing things I expect from them ?)

It's not what you want to do here with unit testing. You do not want to test PDO or any other library, and you are not supposed to test the logic or the behavior of PDO. Be sure that these things have been done by people in charge of PDO.

What you want to test is the correct execution of YOUR code and so the logic of YOUR code. You want to test `getAccountExpirationDate`, and so the results you expect from it. Not the results you expect from PDO calls.

Therefore, and if I understand your code right, you only have to test that the expiration date of the `$Person` you give as parameter has been set with the expected value from `$result` -> If you didn't use PDO in the right way, then the test will fail anyway !

A correct test could be :

- Create a `UserMapper` object and open a DB transaction
- Insert data in DB that will be retrieved in `$result`
- Create a `Person` object with correct `taxId` and `clientID` to get the  wanted `$result` from your query
- Run `UserMapper->getAccountExpirationDate($Person)`
- **Assert** that `$Person->expirationDate` equals whatever you settled as expected from `$result`
- Rollback DB transaction

You may also check the format of the date, etc ... Anything that is related to the logic you implemented.

If you are going to test such things in many tests, use `setUp` and `tearDown` to init and rollback your DB after each test.

Comment: I have edited my question with a higher view and more detailed explanation. I may have cut a lot of the details and reworded it better. I apologize and thank you.

Comment: I dont think you need to test this particular thing with DB integrated tests. The only thing you care about here is that you are getting the date value and mapping it onto the object correctly. As far as DB testing in that case you also should not care what the mapper is doing, you only want to test that you get the results you expect from a query and that should be done in your tests for your `Repository` or whatever you are using to encapsulate DB query building/execution. Even then I would only test things where the query is complex, for example a stat calculation of some sort.

Comment: @prodigitalson So you're saying to test string query itself without the data mapper?

Comment: @Tek No im saying your queries ideally wouldnt happen in the data mapper. The data mapper should only be for mapping the result(s) to the object. The queries should happen in a `Repository` or `Table` type of class. If you are doing this all in the mapper then ok, but normally I would not.

Answer (score 0):

**Is this a legitimate reason to keep both tests?**

I think no one could ever be able to tell from your simple example, which test you need to keep. If you like, you can keep both. I say that because the answer depends a lot on unknown factors of your projects, including future requirements & modifications.

Personally, I don't think you need both, at least for the same function. If your function is more easier to break logically than data-sensitive, feel free to drop the database-backed ones. You will learn to use the correct type of tests over time.

1. **I'm torn because although it is testing for different things, it's essentially duplicate code.**

Yes, it is.

2. **If I get rid of the database test I can't assure the SQL will return the expected information.**

This is a valid concern *if your database gets complicated enough*. You are using DBUnit, so I would assume you have a sample database with sample information. Over time, a production database may gets multiple structure modifications (adding fields, removing fields, even re-working data relationship...). These things will add to your efforts to maintain your test database. However, it would also be helpful if you realize that **some changes in the database aren't right**.

3. **If I get rid of the unit test, I introduce a required database dependency at all times. As the codebase grows, the tests will become more slow over time, no out-of-box testing; extra effort from other developers to set up a configuration.**

What's wrong with requiring a database dependency?

Firstly, I don't see how extra efforts from other developers to setup a configuration comes to play here. You only set up one time, isn't it? In my opinion, it's a minor factor.

Second, the tests will be slow over time. Of course. You can count on in-memory database like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/) or [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) to mitigate that risk, but it certainly take longer. However, do you actually need to worry? Most of these data-backed tests are **integration test**. They should be the responsibility of [Continuous Integration Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration), who runs exhausting test every now and then to prevent regression bug. For developers, I think we should only run a small set of light-weight tests during development.

In the end, I would like to remind you the number 1 rule for using unit test: ***Test what can break***. Don't write tests for test sake. You will never have 100% coverage. However, since 20% of the code is used 80% of the time, focusing your testing effort on your main flow of business might be a good idea.